# windows 8 clients in a domain screen locks after 30 seconds

Tags: windows-8, domain, windows-server-2012-r2

i am an administrator of a domain .
the problem is that all windows 8 clients and all 2012 servers in the domain are getting locked out after 30 seconds of being idle no matter what i do.
windows 7 clients and 2008 servers in the domain do not have that problem oddly enough.
if i install a new windows 8 client it will not have that problem until i join it to the domain. i have tried to disable all Policies except the "default domain policy", and yet nothing helped
i have tried to change the advanced power plan and tried all screen saver options i know in the GPO and nothing helped. any ideas?

Comment: Open a command prompt and type gpresult /scope user /v |
Do the same thing except type: gpresult /scope computer /v | Check through those to see if there are any weird GPOs which might not have been removed. Try gpupdate /force if there are any inconsistencies.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "getting locked out"?  It's going to screensaver and requesting logins, or their account are actually getting locked out of the domain, or?? Have you actually examined the polices defined in the Default Domain Policy you left active?